# Identify a doughnut-shaped free-spinning mower part

Tags: tools, lawn-mower, tool-maintenance

I serviced my mower this morning and gave it a clean with a hose with a moderate level of water pressure. It appears that I have blown a part off the lawn mower though I am not sure how. I can't figure out where the part came from and am hoping someone can identify it so that I can narrow down where it might have come from.

Image of front and back of the part:

*Click image for full size*

[image: front]
[image: back]

The inner part spins free of the outer part and that's about all the information that I have.

The mower I have is a Rover i5500 and the manual is rather light on pictures or diagrams so it was not much help, the manual is also quite easy to find online if that is of any particular help.

Comment: It should be listed as a "bearing" in any parts catalog you look at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at [this manual](http://www.rovermowers.com.au/files/editor_upload/File/04016218-I_ProCut.pdf) (I'm not sure if this is your exact mower), there's an exploded parts view on page 86. I suspect it's the bearing labeled "26" in the diagram. There are several of them, so check each location on your mower.

Comment: Yes if the inner spins separately from the outside, it is a bearing. It probably has a lot of balls or rollers inside, so that it moves freely?  (many years ago I rebuilt a Land Rover gearbox and had a few of these. All were larger, some were loose, but some needed large hammers to remove or re-fit!)

Comment: Thanks for this, just to clarify for anyone else that sees this it was part of the wheel fastening, it looks the wheel on but can spin freely.